# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.15.3) with this library (5.15.2) - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, qt

Trying to run Nsight Compute 2022.4.0.15 gui using `ncu-ui` but get this error.

```bash
$ ncu-ui 
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.15.3) with this library (5.15.2)
```

I think these were the libraries that were installed when I updated my Nvidia GPU driver version to `525.60.11`.

Answer (score 1):

You've encountered this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/+bug/1996459

Comments on that bug report provide some workarounds.